# Fat arrow function React Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to programming and have been taking courses on udemy to learn JS, html and css because I read these were important before jumping into React. I have run into an issue that I cannot seem to explain. The following code executes properly and without error:

```
function FriendLy(props){
        return(
            <div className = "friendLy">
                <Avatar pic = {props.pic}/>
                <Username name = {props.name}/>
                <GetConnected/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

however, the following code returns an "Uncaught ReferenceError"

```
FriendLy = (props) => {
        return(
            <div className = "friendLy">
                <Avatar pic = {props.pic}/>
                <Username name = {props.name}/>
                <GetConnected/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

In my limited knowledge of ES6 and JS, these two expressions should yield the same result. I am using babel which I understand translates ES5 to ES6.

Please educate me on what I am misunderstanding in any and all of the above statements.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are not the same. What is the full error? (also: arrow functions keep the parent's context, i.e. what `this` refers to)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: FriendLy is not defined

Comment: Right, you are assigning something to `FriendLy`, but JS has no idea what `FriendLy` is. That's why you're getting the error.

Comment: I thought I was creating a function called FriendLy

Comment: Not if you start with `FriendLy` instead of `const`, `var` or `let` (or `function`). Also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `const`, `let` or `var` before your variable definition if you're running under [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

```
const FriendLy = (props) => {
   return (
     // ...
   )
}
```

Comment: While this is true, without `const` I'm getting: `ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable FriendLy`

Comment: Thank you,

Wouldn't this be the equivalent of:

const FriendLy = function(props){
   return (
     // ...
   )
}

Comment: @DevinMiller it's almost the same. Both define functions, but the `this` keyword behaves differently inside arrow functions.

Comment: That's interesting. I was under the impression the fat arrow function was strictly a change in syntax. From your answer, it sounds like this is not the case. Thank you

Comment: It is not @DevinMiller there is a change in ```this``` scope and binding. Also, there is an implicit return on things like one-liners.
```const thingReturn = () => thisIsReturned```

Comment: Jacob,
Thanks. I will need to research this scope and binding.

Answer (score 1):

Uou want to make it a function assigned to a variable, so you need to put `const`, `var` or `let` before `FriendLy`:

```
var FriendLy = (props) => {...}
```

Comment: Are you sure on that

Comment: I got the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token, expected ; (4:24)
when applying the first suggestion

Comment: @DevinMiller — The first suggestion is nonsense.

Comment: @Quentin Fixed it now, any better?